# AWS API Gateway DynamoDB GetItem without sort key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I've a Dynamo Db table with following

```
{
  "primary_key": {
    "S": "series"
  },
  "sort_key": {
    "S": "type-of-brokers"
  },
  "title": {
    "S": "Types Of Brokers"
}
,
{
  "primary_key": {
    "S": "series"
  },
  "sort_key": {
    "S": "type-of-brokers-2"
  },
  "title": {
    "S": "Types Of Brokers-2"
}
```

[Following this](https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/) I've implemented application/json body mapping template:

```
{
    "TableName": "table_name",
    "Key" :{
        "primary_key" :{
            "S": "series"
        },
        "sort_key" : {
            "S": "type-of-brokers"
        }
    }
}
```

It returns one item that matched primary and sort key!

Now I want to **return all the matched `primary_key` items i.e. without `sort_key`**

How do I achieve that? with API gateway body mapping template?

Also, can api return common json rather than "S" kind, [here it specify attributes](https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/) , can it be done by not hard coding in `integration response`

Comment: can api return common json rather than "S" kind ? like the Text view in console for edit Item with `DynamoDB JSON` checkbox unchecked?

Comment: If you're using the nodejs sdk you can use the [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) to abstract away the AttributeValues from the dynamodb response.  Other sdks might have similar Clients/abstractions.  AFAIK the api itself will always include the attributevalues by design.

Comment: I'm avoiding AWS Lambda The values are fetched by API Gateway using Body Mapping Templates, mapping can be done to response too. but I don't want to hard code for each response.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `getitem` API requires both hash and sort key. However, you can use `query` api with only hash only.

[Query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property)

> Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value
>   for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the
>   items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can
>   optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a
>   sort key value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression. To
>   further refine the Query results, you can optionally provide a
>   FilterExpression. A FilterExpression determines which items within the
>   results should be returned to you. All of the other results are
>   discarded.

Comment: can api return common json rather than "S" kind ? like the Text view in console for edit Item with `DynamoDB JSON` checkbox unchecked?

Comment: You should get without data type if you use Document client api. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html

Comment: I'm using Api Gateway and dynamodb as appears here : https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/ without lambda functions